# For loop if statement confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, object-literal

I have a JavaScript object literal array that I'm trying to create a simple for loop to pull in all the info. The problem is that I'm trying to use an If statement to close and reopen divs when there are more than 4 books in a row. But when there are more than 4 books it adds these divs to every instance of the book object, creating a row for every item. I just can't for the life of me think what the correct condition is that will only close an reopen the divs every 4 books.

```
    var bookInfo = '';
    var book;


   function print(bookInfo) {
     var outputDiv = document.getElementById('books-go-here');
     outputDiv.innerHTML = bookInfo;
   }

    for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i += 1){
     book = books[i];
     bookInfo += '<div class="large-3 small-6 columns output">';
     bookInfo += '<img src="' + book.image + '"/>';
     bookInfo += '<div class="panel">';
     bookInfo += '<h2>' + book.name + '</h2>';
     bookInfo += '<p>' + book.description + '</p>';
     bookInfo += '</div>';
     bookInfo += '</div>';
     // return bookInfo;
      if (books.length > 4) {
         bookInfo += '</div>"';
         bookInfo += '</div>"';
         bookInfo += '</div>"';
         bookInfo += '<div class="row">';
         bookInfo += '<div class="large-12 columns">';
         bookInfo += '<div id="books-go-here" class="row">';
       }

     }
   print(bookInfo);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is truly pickling my brain at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like you want `if (i%4 == 0)`

Comment: You say "close and reopen". Where where these divs opened initially, where are they going to be closed finally?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the extra HTML after every 4th book, it should be:

```
if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)
```

`i % 4` calculates the remainder of `i/4`, so it's `0` when `i` is `0`, `4`, `8`, etc. The `i > 0` test prevents it from closing before the first book.

You also should have this code at the *beginning* of the `for` loop, not the end. Since counting starts at `0`, after you've printed 4 books, the next iteration will have `i = 4`.

Also, when the loop is done you need to close the last row. That should check `if (books.length > 0)` (if there are 0 books, the loop won't have created any rows, so there's nothing to close).

Comment: It should be before every 4th book, not after.

Comment: Are you sure? If you do that, the first row will have only 3 books, every following row will have 4 books.

Comment: Yes. If you do it after the book, the second row starts after the book with `i == 4`, i.e. the fifth book. You will have five books in the first row and four in the remaining rows. Also, if the last row has four books there will be another empty row after it.

Comment: The thing is that if you start the count at 0 in this situation, you get the divs closed after the first element 0%4 === 0. And then 4,8,12 ...

Comment: That's why I have `i > 0` in the test.

Comment: The check after the loop is not needed when the code is created this way. There should *always* be code after the loop to close the last row, as it will never be closed by the code in the loop.

Comment: Right again. It needs to check if there are any books, though. Otherwise it will close the rows when it didn't open any.

Comment: @Barmar: The loop doesn't open the first row, that is opened before the loop, so there shouldn't be any check after the loop, it should always close the row.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about using % This JavaScript business is so difficult to learn!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will have mismatched div tags.  You can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i += 1){
 book = books[i];
  if (i % 4 == 0) {
     bookInfo += '<div class="row">';
     bookInfo += '<div class="large-12 columns">';
     bookInfo += '<div id="books-go-here" class="row">';
  }
 bookInfo += '<div class="large-3 small-6 columns output">';
 bookInfo += '<img src="' + book.image + '"/>';
 bookInfo += '<div class="panel">';
 bookInfo += '<h2>' + book.name + '</h2>';
 bookInfo += '<p>' + book.description + '</p>';
 bookInfo += '</div>';
 bookInfo += '</div>';
 // return bookInfo;
  if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
   }

 }

 if (books.length % 4 != 0){
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your example and it does the job. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You would use the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
```

The value of `i % 4` will go from 0 to 3 and then start from 0 again as `i` inscreases. You want to make a new line each time the value is 0, except for the very first time.

Also, you want to do that in the beginning of the code in the loop, so that you create a new row before the first item in each row:

```
for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i += 1){
  if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '<div class="row">';
     bookInfo += '<div class="large-12 columns">';
     bookInfo += '<div id="books-go-here" class="row">';
   }
   book = books[i];
   bookInfo += '<div class="large-3 small-6 columns output">';
   bookInfo += '<img src="' + book.image + '"/>';
   bookInfo += '<div class="panel">';
   bookInfo += '<h2>' + book.name + '</h2>';
   bookInfo += '<p>' + book.description + '</p>';
   bookInfo += '</div>';
   bookInfo += '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: You want `i' instead of books.length

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable that each time it gets to 3, you close the div and clear it to 0:

```
for(var i = 0, k = 0; i < books.length; i++, k++){
 book = books[i];
 bookInfo += '<div class="large-3 small-6 columns output">';
 bookInfo += '<img src="' + book.image + '"/>';
 bookInfo += '<div class="panel">';
 bookInfo += '<h2>' + book.name + '</h2>';
 bookInfo += '<p>' + book.description + '</p>';
 bookInfo += '</div>';
 bookInfo += '</div>';
 // return bookInfo;
  if (k === 3) {
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '</div>"';
     bookInfo += '<div class="row">';
     bookInfo += '<div class="large-12 columns">';
     bookInfo += '<div id="books-go-here" class="row">';
     k = 0;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're checking if the `books` array length is greater than four, and if it is, for each step it will close and reopen. 
You need to follow these steps:

- Start the count from 1 (`var i = 1`)
- Update the stop condition to say `; i <= books.length ;`
- divide `i` (which is incrementing at every iteration step), by 4 and check for the remainder of that operation.

This changes your code to:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= books.length; i += 1){
  // process stuff, create dom strings
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    // close divs
  }
}
```

Let me know if this is not clear enough.